# Powershell - Get desktop path for all users [OneDrive Sync on some of them]

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search all user's desktops for a particular shortcut and I find difficulties enumerate all desktop paths for different users on the computer as some of them have OneDrive sync and the standard path c:\Users\%user%\Desktop is not to be found.
I have tried getting the path with the GetFolderPath which only returns the path to the current user:

```
[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

So briefly the path scenarios are:

1. C:\users\username\Desktop
2. C:\users\username\One Drive - Company\Desktop

I would be glad if somebody has a hint how to find all paths in this mixed environment.

Comment: The "real" desktop location for each user is located in the following registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" in the Desktop value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my older training script. I don't know how (or if any) it works with `OneDrive` cync as I have `OneDrive` disabled (or even uninstalled) because I found it extremely irritating…

```
Remove-Variable path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Verbose "--- Special Folders ---" -Verbose
$SpecialFolders = @{}
$names = [Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames( [Environment+SpecialFolder])
ForEach ($name in $names) {
    # assign and then check
    if( $path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath($name) ){ 
        $SpecialFolders[$name] = $path
    } else {
        Write-Warning $name
        $SpecialFolders[$name] = ''
    }
}
$SpecialFolders.GetEnumerator() | 
    Sort-Object -Property name #| Format-Table -AutoSize
"---"

###Pause
$ShellFolders=@{}
Write-Verbose "--- Shell Folders ---" -Verbose
[System.Enum]::GetValues([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $ShellFolders[$_.ToString()] = 
            ($_.value__, [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath($_))
    }
$ShellFolders.GetEnumerator() | 
    Sort-Object -Property name # | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Using this script got me to `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')` which worked perfectly to properly return the current user's OneDrive synced Desktop folder.  I had previously been using `($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop` which, whilst it was definitely still in existence, no longer contained the user's visible desktop contents.